# Prove for any closed curve $C$ then the path integral is independent of the path between points $p$ and $q$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, greens-theorem

Prove that if $$\oint_C \vec{B}.d\vec{r}=0$$ for any closed curve $C$, then the path intergral $$\int_P^Q\vec{B}.d\vec{r}$$ is independent of the path taken between points $P$ and $Q$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any two paths between $P$ and $Q$ form a closed loop by traversing one path from $P$ to $Q$ and then the other path from $Q$ back to $P$. Integrating around this path gives you zero but it also gives you the path integral on the first path from $P$ to $Q$ plus the negative of the integral on the second path from $P$ to $Q$.

Answer (score 3):

**Outline:** Let $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ be two paths from $P$ to $Q$. Then the path made by following $\gamma_1$, then $\gamma_2$ traversed in the opposite direction (often written $\gamma_2^{-1}\gamma_1$ or $\gamma_1-\gamma_2$) is a closed curve. Also, by additivity in the path, $\int_{\gamma_1-\gamma_2} = \int_{\gamma_1}-\int_{\gamma_2}$.